# Passing signalr through an another api then to the website

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, signalr

We have a backend API with signalr endpoint that pass the correct date but are website still on top of the front-end API and is not allowed to directly communicate with the backend API is there away to pass the signal through the frontend API 
Both API are written in asp core and the website is angular
The data being passed is a model there is currently in one hub so far at /API/hubs/score which pass data out every few minutes

Comment: why don't you use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-signalr in the angular app?

Comment: Hi I have the signalr setup in my angular and if I connect to my backend it works but in production the website it not allowed to speak directly to the backend so we wondering is it possible to pass the hub through the front end api

Comment: So, either you can create an event listener or you can add signalr support on all three components of your whole application suite.

Comment: That's what I am trying to figure out getting the front-end API to listen to the signal and pass it to the front-end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to Jose I figured out an answer which was setting up my frontend API the a signalr client that was activated on a certain API call that started listening to the backend signal and was I did was retransmission through the front-end to the angular page